# Corporate speak for customers & partners

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a "corporate speak" noun that describes both customers and partners of a given company.
"Ecosystem" is the closest I've come, but I'd like more options.

Answer (score 3):

At my wife's previous company they used to refer to them collectively as **stakeholders**.

> a person such as an employee, customer, or citizen who is involved with an organization, society, etc. and therefore has responsibilities towards it and an interest in its success

[Cambridge On-line](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stakeholder)

Comment: Good answer. Better with a reference.